# 自分が回答した質問へのクローズ票の禁止

Tags: 機能の要求

自分が回答した質問へのクローズ票投票と、クローズ票を投票した質問への回答を禁止してください

- 回答できるのであれば回答不能系のクローズ理由には該当しない
- 「主観的な回答しか集まらない」「オフトピック」など回答規制系のクローズ理由であれば回答すべきでない

のですから、クローズ票と回答を両方行うのは行為として矛盾していますし、できる必要も無いはずです。判断が間違っていたのであれば、回答を削除してクローズ投票する、投票を取り消して回答することもできます。

また、クローズ投票を本来の目的から離れて他の回答を制限しようという意図で行うことにも繋がります。

---

追記

SOのクローズというシステムは、Q&Aのリソースとしての質を維持するために、質が低いであろう事が想定される回答を制限したり、リソースの重複を防止するための機能だと理解しています。

回答とクローズ投票を両方行うのは上記の観点において矛盾した行為であるし、悪用すること**も**できる、という説明として3項目を箇条書きにしたのですが、「悪用を防ぐために制限すべきである」と解釈されてしまったので、ちょっと書き直しました。

Comment: 昨日やってしまいました。もっとも最初は何らかの役に立つことを書いたつもりだったのですが、質問者に別の意図が読み取れた時点でクローズ票を入れました。その回答は削除しても良いと思っています。

Answer (score 4):

以下のような理由で反対です。

- コメント欄では書ききれないので回答として書く場合がある
- 正確な回答はできなくても方向性の提示は可能な場合がある
- 第三者の回答に対するレスポンスとして回答をする場合がある

Comment: クローズが成立した時点で投票者であろうがなかろうが回答はできなくなりますので、挙げられたような理由は積極的な不都合とは言いがたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

(質問の編集を受けて、有効な部分だけを残しておきます。が、全然質問自体の得票が伸びないですね、、時間があるときがあれば、また考えてみます)

## クローズ票の定義について

クローズ票についての機能なので、まず、クローズ票をコミュニティとしてどう取り扱うかを定義しないと、議論がぶれると思いました。
今回の機能要求の文脈や、 @suzukis さんからのコメントを踏まえて考えると、クローズ票は「(Q&Aリソースとしての質の維持のために)この質問に対する回答はこれ以上コミュニティとして許容するべきではない」ということをコミュニティのメンバーとして表す意思表明である、と捉えるのがよいのではないかと考えています。

## ケース: 回答後の重複クローズ

重複に対するクローズ票は、「回答規制系」のクローズ票に該当すると考えています。(違ったら、ご指摘お願いします。結論が変わります。)

ありうる話なのかな、と思ったのが、「最初は普通に回答してみたけど、後々調べてみたら、既に重複する質問を見つけた」場合です。

このケースだと、回答前には (まったく) 持っていなかった「クローズ対象であるという確信」が、回答後しばらくしてから発生する構造があるのだと理解しています。

クローズ投票の定義が、「これより先は、回答を受け付けるべきではない」という意思表示であるならば、このケースにおいては、「回答後のクローズ」は、理屈上は問題ないのではないか、と思っています。この場合のクローズ投票のイメージは、「ヘイみんな、この質問は重複だって判明したからこれ以上の回答をとりやめようぜ」です。この人が、その前に回答をしていたとしても、スジは通っていると思っています。

## 結論

クローズ票の定義上、「クローズ票投票後に回答ができなくなる」のは、システムとしてあってもいいと思います。
「回答後の重複クローズ」のケースを考えると、「回答した質問へのクローズ投票の禁止」にはひとまず反対です。

Comment: もうちょっと考えた結果、多分、問題になるのは「クローズされた質問に対するすでにある回答たちの、信用度独占に対しての公平性の問題」なのかな、と思いました。それは、もしそれを議論するなら、このトピックではなく別トピックなのかな、と思っています。

Comment: 成立しなかったら回答しようと思っているような人であればクローズ票を投じないで他のユーザーに任せればいいのですからこれも積極的な不都合とは言いがたいと思います。そもそも、クローズさせたいが成立するかわからない、成立しなかったら回答しよう、というような曖昧な態度でクローズ票を投票するのが間違っていますし、それこそそちらの方が「価値提供の阻害」を招いています。

Comment: @suzukis うーん、そうか。回答規制系の投票をしながら、自身は回答をしている人間がいること自体が、コミュニティとしての「価値提供の阻害」になっている、ということでしょうか。

Comment: ここで問題にしているのは「故意に他人の回答を妨害できる」ことなので、+/-投票の制限によって結果的に「プラス票の独占」は回避できるとしても、それが「正しい」機能要求であるという意見には同意できません。 / 現状のシステムにおいて「回答後に重複であることを発見したのでクローズ票を投票する」人であれば、「回答を削除したうえでクローズ票を投票する」ことも期待できるのではないでしょうか。逆に、プラス票を理由に回答の削除と投票をためらう人が現状のシステムではクローズ票を投票するはずと言えますか。条件設定に無理があるように思えます。

Comment: @suzukis (前半部分について)この機能要求が解決したい実際的な問題は、「クローズされた(ている)問題に対するプラス投票の独占という事象」ではなくって、それを狙っての「故意による他人の回答の妨害」であるということでしょうか。だとすると、このメタ質問(の三番目の理由)がミスリーディングで、「この機能が無いと、他の回答を制限できうるから、プラス投票を独占できてしまう」という主張ではなく、「この機能がないと、プラス投票独占のために、クローズ投票を本来の意図とは違った形で悪用され得てしまう」があるべき機能要求理由なのかな、と思いました。

Comment: @suzukis (後半部分) 一回書いたものを、書き直ししようとして、削除したら、元書いてあった内容を忘れてしまいました。。ただ、後半部分について、自分の主張がすこしおかしいと思ったので、その部分を修正しました。

Comment: @suzukis 妨害行為のためのクローズ投票が問題だとして、何を持ってそのクローズ投票が妨害行為だと定義するのかが、問題だと思いました。回答のケースであげた回答後のクローズ投票が許されるとしたならば、この投票と妨害行為はどうやったら判断ができるのか？が問題になると思っています。

Comment: 「悪用を防ぐために制限を加えるべきだ」という主張ではないのですがそのようにとらえられてしまっているようなので、質問を編集しました。